Ring Buffer Implementation in C++
The following code is designed for handling real-time messages. It assumes there will be only two threads using the RingBuffer object:

A provider thread calls the push method to construct new message object.
A consumer thread calls the acquire_next and front methods to retrieve the next message object in the queue.

It is a major objective to keep the latency low. Welcome any comments, especially on thread safety and latency related subjects.
ringbuffer.h
#ifndef __RINGBUFFER_H
#define __RINGBUFFER_H

#include <cstdlib>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>


template <typename T, typename... ConstructorArgs>  // ConstructorArgs are the argument types for T's Constuctor
class RingBuffer {
public:
    RingBuffer(const size_t buffer_size): buffer_size(buffer_size), provider_idx(1), consumer_idx(0) {
        this -> buffer = (T*)(new unsigned char[buffer_size * sizeof(T)]);
    }

    ~RingBuffer() {
        delete [] (this -> buffer);
    }

    void push(const ConstructorArgs&... args) {

        size_t next_idx = (provider_idx + 1) % this -> buffer_size;
        while (next_idx == consumer_idx) std::this_thread::yield();

        new (&this -> buffer[provider_idx]) T(args...);

        this -> provider_idx = next_idx;
    }

    T& acquire_next() {
        size_t next_idx = (consumer_idx + 1) % this -> buffer_size;
        while (next_idx == provider_idx) std::this_thread::yield();

        this -> consumer_idx = next_idx;
        return this -> buffer[this -> consumer_idx];
    }

    T& front() {
        return this -> buffer[this -> consumer_idx];
    }

private:
    const size_t buffer_size;
    std::atomic<size_t> provider_idx, consumer_idx;
    T * buffer;
};


#endif  // __RINGBUFFER_H

Here is a sample main.cpp which uses the RingBuffer class.
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include "ringbuffer.h"


#define BUFSIZE 64
#define ITERATIONS 1000
#define CONSUMER_INTERVAL 0  // ms
#define PROVIDER_INTERVAL 10


class TestClass {

public:
    TestClass(int a, char b): a(a), b(b){}

    void print(void) {
        std::cout << a << ' ' << b << std::endl;
        return;
    }

private:
    int a;
    char b;
};


void provider_routine(RingBuffer<TestClass, int, char> *buffer) {

    for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
        buffer -> push(i, (char)(i % 128));
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(PROVIDER_INTERVAL));
    }

    return;
}


int main(void) {

    RingBuffer<TestClass, int, char> *buffer = new RingBuffer<TestClass, int, char>(BUFSIZE);

    std::thread provider_thread(provider_routine, buffer);

    for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
        std::cout << "acquiring" << std::endl;
        buffer -> acquire_next().print();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(CONSUMER_INTERVAL));
    }

    provider_thread.join();

    delete buffer;
    return 0;
}



Micro-review: you've misspelt std::size_t all the way through.

Might have a look at boost::lockfree::spsc_queue.

#ifndef __RINGBUFFER_H

__RINGBUFFER_H is an illegal identifier. Identifiers beginning with an underscore are not allowed at global scope, and identifiers with double-underscores are not allowed anywhere.
#include <cstdlib>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

When dealing with includes, it is generally a good idea to order them in a logical and consistent way. This is because headers are just textually puked right into the translation unit, so the order matters; one header’s contents could conceivably change the meaning of another’s. It would be a poorly-designed header that does this, true, but the fact remains, and the compiler needs to account for that possibility.
A good rule of thumb is to group headers by library, and then sort alphabetically.
template <typename T, typename... ConstructorArgs>  // ConstructorArgs are the argument types for T's Constuctor
class RingBuffer {

It’s a little silly to make the entire container class depend on the constructor arguments. Does it really make sense that a ring buffer of strings constructed from char arrays should be different from a ring buffer of strings constructed from string views which should also be different from a ring buffer of strings that are copy constructed? Doesn’t it make sense to just have a ring buffer of strings? And who cares how the strings happen to be constructed? They’re all strings.
The T template argument is also in dire need of constraints. I mean, you obviously don’t intend for RingBuffer<void, ...> to be possible, right? What about RingBuffer<int&, ...>? Probably not. So at the very least T should be an object.
    RingBuffer(const size_t buffer_size): buffer_size(buffer_size), provider_idx(1), consumer_idx(0) {
        this -> buffer = (T*)(new unsigned char[buffer_size * sizeof(T)]);
    }

First, it’s std::size_t, not just size_t. You can get away without the std:: in most compilers for historical reasons… but that won’t be true in the future.
Now, you have some serious bugs going on. For starters, you are not aligning this buffer you’re creating.
I would strongly suggest you don’t try screwing around with low-level memory crap, and instead just add allocator support to your type. It would not only make things so much easier, it would prevent entire classes of bugs, and, as a free benefit, make your class constexpr capable with zero effort.
Adding allocator support to your class is as easy as 1-2-3. Step 1: add an allocator template parameter:
template<typename T, typename Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
class RingBuffer
{

Step 2: add a data member for the allocator, and constructors for setting it:
template<typename T, typename Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
class RingBuffer
{
public:
    
    RingBuffer(std::size_t buffer_size, Allocator const& allocator = Allocator{})
        : buffer_size{buffer_size}
        , provider_idx{1}
        , consumer_idx{0}
        , _allocator{allocator}
    {
        // ...
    }

    // ...

private:
    std::size_t buffer_size;
    std::atomic<std::size_t> provider_idx
    std::atomic<std::size_t> consumer_idx;
    T* buffer;
    [[no_unique_address]] _allocator;
};

Step 3: actually use the allocator:
template<typename T, typename Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
class RingBuffer
{
public:
    
    constexpr RingBuffer(std::size_t buffer_size, Allocator const& allocator = Allocator{})
        : buffer_size{buffer_size}
        , provider_idx{1}
        , consumer_idx{0}
        , _allocator{allocator}
    {
        // Automatically correctly aligned, pointer has proper
        // provenance, etc..
        buffer = std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::allocate(_allocator, buffer_size);
    }

    ~RingBuffer()
    {
        std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::deallocate(_allocator, buffer, buffer_size);
    }


    template<typename... Args>
        requires std::constructible_from<T, Args...>
    constexpr auto push(Args&&... args)
        noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<T, Args...>)
    {
        auto const next_idx = ++provider_idx.load(std::memory_order::acquire) % buffer_size;
        while (next_idx == consumer_idx)
            std::this_thread::yield();

        // Avoids a massive laundry list of potential problems with the
        // placement new expression, and is even constexpr (pre C++26).
        std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::construct(_allocator, buffer + next_idx, std::forward<Args>(args)...);

        provider_idx.store(next_idx, std::memory_order::release);
    }

    // ...

private:
    std::size_t buffer_size;
    std::atomic<std::size_t> provider_idx
    std::atomic<std::size_t> consumer_idx;
    T* buffer;
    [[no_unique_address]] _allocator;
};

It would take several thousand words to cover the massive pile of bugs and other issues that exist in your code right now, that would be trivially solved by just using allocators rather than dicking around with manual, low-level memory operations. And allocators add exactly zero cost or overhead (and, in fact, allow for even more efficient use cases, like stack allocation, if desired).
Now back to your constructor.
    RingBuffer(const size_t buffer_size): buffer_size(buffer_size), provider_idx(1), consumer_idx(0) {
        this -> buffer = (T*)(new unsigned char[buffer_size * sizeof(T)]);
    }

Notice that you skip over the first element in your buffer, and start the provider index at 1. That means that when you start construct elements in your buffer, there will be an empty hole at the beginning. Nowhere in your code do you account for that. (Granted, this class is positively riddled with bugs and there are a ton of other bugs that make this bug irrelevant. But still, if/when everything else is working, having that hole at the start of your buffer is going to bite you in the ass.)
Also, as a matter of style, C++ coders generally don’t put the explicit this in front of every data member and member function call. I mean, you don’t even use it consistently yourself. It’s just noise.
Also also, the spaces around the -> are a poor stylistic choice. You don’t put spaces around the . when doing member access, now do you?
    ~RingBuffer() {
        delete [] (this -> buffer);
    }

Are we forgetting something?
You’ve deleted the buffer… but what about the stuff that’s IN the buffer?
In fact, the bugs here go deeper than that. Because let’s not forget where buffer came from. You allocated an unsigned char array of size sizeof(T) * buffer_size, and then you (C-style!!!) casted it to a T*. You did NOT allocate a T array.
But now you’re trying to delete a T array. (And an unaligned one at that.) I’d actually be curious to see how this blows up with different compilers and hardware. It could be a spectacular crash.
What thou do-est, thou must undo-est, nothing more, nothing less, and thou must do-est it in strict reverse order. You allocated an unsigned char array, then cast it to a T*, then constructed zero or more T objects in some specific order. Therefore, you must destroy those zero or more T objects… in the correct order (reverse of construction order)… and then “un-cast” the T* back to unsigned char*, and then destroy the array. Anything else is wrong.
Also, there is a rule in C++ called the rule of 3/5/0. If your class needs any of:

the destructor
the copy constructor; or
the copy assignment operator

… then it almost certainly needs all three. And it could probably use a move constructor and move assignment operator, too.
Since you need a destructor, you need to either define or delete the copy operations (and probably the move ops as well).
    void push(const ConstructorArgs&... args) {

This is not the correct way to forward arguments.
First, this should be a template function. It is not. The class is a template, but this function is a plain old non-template member function (of a template class).
Second, taking the arguments by const& makes moving impossible, which may be required for some cases.
The correct form of a function that forwards its arguments is:
template<typename... Args>
auto push(Args&&... args)
{

And then you use the arguments with std::forward<Args>(args)....
But while we’re at it, we should also constrain this template function:
template<typename... Args>
    requires std::constructible_from<T, Args...>
auto push(Args&&... args)
{

And this:
        new (&this -> buffer[provider_idx]) T(args...);

… is just plain wrong, for like a dozen reasons not worth getting into here. Just don’t do low-level crap like this. It’s not worth the grief. Use std::construct_at(), or, better, allocators and allocator_traits<Allocator>::construct()… don’t do &buffer[n], do buffer + n… and of course properly forward your arguments:
    std::construct_at(buffer + provider_idx.load(...), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    // or
    std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::construct(_allocator, buffer + provider_idx.load(...), std::forward<Args>(args)...);

Now let’s focus on the next two lines:
        size_t next_idx = (provider_idx + 1) % this -> buffer_size;
        while (next_idx == consumer_idx) std::this_thread::yield();

First, let’s clean it up into more readable C++:
auto const next_idx = (provider_idx + 1) % buffer_size;
while (next_idx == consumer_idx)
    std::this_thread::yield();

Now, as a first pass to optimizing this, we want to avoid requiring sequential consistency if we don’t really need it… and we don’t, we can use acquire-release semantics:
auto const next_idx = ++provider_idx.load(std::memory_order::acquire) % buffer_size;
while (next_idx == consumer_idx.load(std::memory_order::acquire))
    std::this_thread::yield();

For the comparison, we could probably go further, and even use relaxed semantics. The upside is that if the provider thread doesn’t have to wait, it will breeze through to the rest of the function lightning fast. Relaxed semantics are safe because so long as the provider isn’t caught up to the consumer, it doesn’t really matter where exactly the consumer is: there will always be room (even if the consumer does anything, that just means there will be more room). The downside is that when it does have to wait, it might have to wait a bit longer to “see” the changes made by the consumer thread.
But there’s another problem. Consider two different situations.

First, consider what happens if you give up your entire time slice (via yield()), but then a slot opens up almost immediately. Too bad; you’re stuck sleeping until the next time the thread scheduler gets around to waking you up.
Second, consider what happens if you have to wait for quite a while for a slot to open up. The thread keeps waking up pointlessly, seeing there’s still no slot, then going back to sleep, over and over.

In other words, unless you hit the sweet spot where either the slot is already available or you only have to wait slightly less than one thread time slice, this strategy is not optimal.
The solution is simple, though. Don’t manually spin-wait. Use wait functions.
auto const next_idx = ++provider_idx.load(std::memory_order::acquire) % buffer_size;
consumer_idx.wait(next_idx, std::memory_order::relaxed);

So let’s put it all together:
template<typename... Args>
    requires std::constructible_from<T, Args...>
constexpr auto push(Args&&... args)
    // optional, but why not:
    noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<T, Args...>)
{
    auto const curr_idx = provider_idx.load(std::memory_order::acquire);
    auto const next_idx = (curr_idx + 1) % buffer_size;
    consumer_idx.wait(next_idx, std::memory_order::relaxed);

    std::construct_at(buffer + curr_idx, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    // or
    std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::construct(_allocator, buffer + curr_idx, std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    provider_idx.store(next_idx, std::memory_order::release);
    provider_idx.notify_one();
}

I would also suggest a try_push() function, that does not wait; if there is no space, it returns immediately. This can be a handy addition to the interface, because it makes it possible for client code to opportunistically do other stuff if the buffer is full, and come back to it later maybe.
Now, you have a push function… but no pop function. Does this not set off alarms for you? You have a finite space—it’s a ring buffer, after all—but you continuously construct objects, and never destroy them. Which means, in practice, you are probably stomping all over previously-constructed objects.
And that should be obvious from the structure of .push() and .acquire_next(), which are mirror opposites of each other:



Step
.push()
.acquire_next()




Calculate next index
size_t next_idx = (provider_idx …
size_t next_idx = (consumer_idx …


Wait
while (next_idx == consumer_idx …
while (next_idx == provider_idx …


!!!
new ( …
???


Adjust index
this -> provider_idx = next_idx;
this -> consumer_idx = next_idx;


Return
return; // implicit
return buffer[next_idx];



With the symmetry you can see not only what is missing, but where it is missing from.
(And no, don’t do a manual delete to match the manual new (in fact, get rid of that, too). Use std::destroy_at().)
Because of the symmetry with .push(), pretty much everything else that applies to .push() applies to .acquire_next().
As for .front()…:
    T& front() {
        return this -> buffer[this -> consumer_idx];
    }

This function is incredibly dangerous. I mean, obviously it can’t be called before .push()… you can’t expect there to be anything at the front of the buffer until after you’ve pushed something. But the really zany thing is that the following code is also wrong:
auto buf = RingBuffer<TestClass, int, char>(BUFSIZE);
buf.push(1, 'a');
auto x = buf.front(); // CRASH!

You would think that after pushing something to the buffer, there would be something at the front of the buffer. But, no. Because in the constructor, you created that hole at the front of the array, remember? That’s the hole we’re now crashing into.
My advice would be to throw out .front(), and instead have a pair of acquire functions that are symmetrical with the pair of push functions. One waits for something to become available and then returns a reference to it. The other checks if something is available, and if so returns a reference to it, and if not immediately returns some form of null. In other words, to match .push() and .try_push(), you’d have .front() and .try_front() (or .acquire() and .try_acquire(), or whatever).
Except… and here’s where things get really hairy… what happens if the provider runs out before the consumer?
Your test code is, to put it mildly, hardly much of a test. It uses very simple types… which is why you probably aren’t seeing massive crashes or memory corruption from all the overwriting going on. And… and this is a very deep point… it runs both the provider and consumer functions exactly the same number of times.
The reason why this is important is because that hides serious design flaws.
Consider what happens if you run the provider loop 1000 times, but the consumer loop only 10 times. The buffer will eventually fill up… and then the provider thread will freeze. And… freeze. And… stay frozen. Waiting forever for the buffer to clear up space so it can push more stuff. But that will never happen. It will wait for eternity (or at least until the process is killed).
Or consider the opposite scenario, where you run the consumer loop 1000 times, but the provider loop only 10 times. Now the consumer thread will starve and… freeze. Forever. Waiting. For the next item that will never come. How sad.
How can you fix this?
I mean… you can’t. This design is just hopelessly broken. Indeed, if the number of times the producer and consumer threads loop is greater than the size of the buffer—which, I mean, if that never happens, then what is the point of a ring buffer?—and either one of those two threads loops even just one more time than the other… deadlock.
I’ll be blunt. There is no way to fix this. The design idea is fundamentally flawed.
If you want a design that works, there are two options:

You can’t hide the synchronization inside the class. In other words, you can’t have the member functions do the waiting. The waiting has to happen outside, where it can be controlled, and perhaps timed-out, or whatever else. Put more generally, there has to be a second, out-of-band channel of information to signal when to stop waiting for space (in the provider case) or elements (in the consumer case), and a means to actually stop any waiting.
Provide a means to “close” the buffer, which will immediately stop any waiting. In other words, if the provider is finished, it can close the buffer, and the consumer can continue grabbing any leftover elements until the buffer is empty, at which point trying to acquire the next will immediately return an empty notice. (Or, vice versa: the consumer end can close the buffer, and the next attempt to push will fail.) Put another way, build a second channel of information, to signal when “done” and stop any waiting, into the class itself.

Either option will require a complete redesign.
There is currently a proposal for something like what you are making, called std::bounded_queue. It uses option 2: a “close” function.
Anywho, on with the review.
private:
    const size_t buffer_size;
    std::atomic<size_t> provider_idx, consumer_idx;
    T * buffer;

Never use const data members. It is an anti-pattern, and it breaks your class.
Don’t write multiple declarations on a single line. One declaration per line, please. Your code won’t run any faster if you squash it all on one line, and making stuff harder to spot is an easy way to create bugs.
And there is too much space in T * buffer. That looks like a multiplication operation. The C++ convention is T* buffer.
I know the main.cpp is just sample code, but there’s still quite a bit in there to comment on.
#define BUFSIZE 64
#define ITERATIONS 1000
#define CONSUMER_INTERVAL 0  // ms
#define PROVIDER_INTERVAL 10

Do not use macros for this kind of thing. In fact, do not use the preprocessor at all, except for #include and include guards (and even those are on the way out now that modules are a thing).
Also, this is particularly silly:
#define CONSUMER_INTERVAL 0  // ms

Because later you do this:
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(CONSUMER_INTERVAL));

The whole point of the chrono types is so you don’t need to use comments or other shady means to specify the time scale. It’s right there: milliseconds. You just have it in the wrong place.
So the above constants should be:
using namespace std::chrono::literals;

constexpr auto bufsize = 64uz;
constexpr auto iterations = 1000;
constexpr auto consumer_interval = 0ms;
constexpr auto provider_interval = 10ms;

On to TestClass:
    void print(void) {
        std::cout << a << ' ' << b << std::endl;
        return;
    }

Writing void in an empty function argument list is an archaic C practice that has never been necessary nor meaningful in C++. (And I think it’s even obsolete in C now, too.)
There is no need to write return; at the end of a function returning nothing.
Never use std::endl; it is always wrong.
There is a standard spelling for print():
class TestClass
{
public:
    // ... [snip] ...

    template<typename Char, typename Traits>
    friend auto operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>& o, TestClass const& v)
        -> std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>& o
    {
        auto oss = std::ostringstream{};
        oss.imbue(std::locale::classic());

        oss << v.a << ' ' << v.b;

        o << std::move(oss).str().c_str();
        return o;
    }

    // ... [snip] ...
};

It’s more verbose, but it turns:
        std::cout << "acquiring" << std::endl;
        buffer -> acquire_next().print();

… into:
        std::cout << "acquiring\n" << buffer->acquire_next() << '\n';

Finally, in main():
    RingBuffer<TestClass, int, char> *buffer = new RingBuffer<TestClass, int, char>(BUFSIZE);

There is really no need for new here. You could just as easily do:
    auto buffer = RingBuffer<TestClass, int, char>{bufsize};

… and now you don’t need to delete.
And finally:
    std::thread provider_thread(provider_routine, buffer);

Prefer to use jthread in new code. That way you don’t need to manually join.
With all that, main() becomes:
auto main() -> int
{
    auto buffer = RingBuffer<TestClass, int, char>{bufsize};

    auto provider_thread = std::jthread{provider_routine, &buffer};

    for (auto i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "acquiring\n" << buffer.acquire_next() << '\n';
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(consumer_interval);
    }
}

In general, prefer stuff that does not require manual cleanup. The same logic goes for why using new to allocate the ring buffer is unwise; either don’t use new at all and let the buffer be automatically cleaned up when the stack unwinds, or use a smart pointer. Never use raw delete.

The code does appear thread-safe at a glance, at least with the undocumented assumption that only 1 producer thread and 1 consumer thread use a given buffer at any time.
There are, unfortunately, a lot of issues beyond thread-safety & latency.
Invalid Header Guards
Symbols starting with an underscore at global scope -- which includes macros -- are reserved to the implementation.
A trailing underscore is OK, but two consecutive underscores are also reserved.
No Namespace
It is poor style to define symbols in the global namespace, this is not C.
No Contract
The contract is undocumented. Specifically, this seems to only work with a single producer & a single consumer, but this restriction is not documented, much less enforced.
Unexpected Template Arguments
It is completely unnecessary for RingBuffer to have ConstructorArgs as type arguments, when they are only necessary in the push method.
On top of being ungainly -- the arguments have to be specified whenever the type is -- it also unnecessarily restricts the user from calling push with different sets of arguments, for no gain.
Just make push template.
No validation of buffer_size
You never validate that buffer_size is 0. This is bad, because taking % this->buffer_size if it's 0 is Undefined Behavior.
Also, consider forcing buffer_size to be a power-of-2, or rounding it to the next power-of-2, and using a mask instead. Integer division is the slowest arithmetic instruction on a CPU, clocking in at up to 90 cycles for a 64-bits integer (when an addition is 1 cycle).
Unaligned buffer
While the buffer is correctly signed, it is not correctly aligned.
Using an under-aligned buffer is Undefined Behavior.
Inconsistent Prefixing
Some uses of data-members are prefixed by this->, others are not. Pick a standard and stick to it.
Needless abbreviation
Using idx instead of index saves two characters, it's really not worth it.
Aggregated declarations
It is generally considered poor style to declare multiple variables or data-members at once, split the declaration of provider_idx and consumer_idx.
Separate initialization of data-members
provider_idx and consumer_idx are initialized with constants, just initialize them at their declaration site.
Insufficient integer width
On a 32-bits machine, size_t may overflow (relatively) easily, and I'm not quite sure your logic accounts for that.
Use std::uint64_t instead, to guarantee the absence of overflow.
Const data-member.
Const data-members are generally more trouble than they are worth, they prevent assignment for example.
It's also inconsistent to have buffer_size be const but not buffer.
Save yourself the trouble, remove the const.
Leaks
The destructor does not destroy the elements remaining in the buffer.
Neither push nor pop do, either.
Unnecessarily restricted push arguments
It's up to the user to decide whether the constructor arguments should be value, references, r-value references, etc... do not use const ...& for them.
Also, once that is fixed, you'll need to fix the constructor call to properly forward the reference type: T(std::forward<ConstructorArgs>(args)...).
Sequentially Consistent
By not specifying any memory ordering, you are using the default one: Sequentially Consistent.
This is the heaviest duty memory ordering available, so it's definitely good enough, but it's also unnecessarily costly.
If you do not know which memory orderings to use, at the very least attempt to minimize the number of operations you perform on the atomics...
... for example, using the non-atomic next_idx instead of the atomic provider_idx or consumer_idx when accessing the buffer (possibly adjusted).
Invalid front
The front method is incorrect: if no element has been pushed, it will return a reference to an uninitialized object.
There's no point for it anyway. If the user called acquire_next to get a reference to the next element, properly synchronized, they have the reference and shouldn't need to get it again.
No automatic test
The test provided is not automatic.
Automate the tests by checking various scenarios and at the very least using assert or exceptions to signal failures... though I encourage you to use a test framework: Google Test, Catch2, ... pick your poison.
Incomplete tests
When designing a test for a container class (or similar) the data element you use should seek to exercise multiple issues:

Under Alignment: an over aligned item, ie with a greater alignment than std::max_align_t.
Leak: an item which allocates memory, such as std::string, or better yet, which ensures that the memory pointer is nulled in its destructor, so an attempt to access a destroyed element immediately crashes.

Your TestClass is woefully incomplete in this regard.
Unnecessary return
There is no reason to write return; at the end of provider_routine.
(Or return 0; at the end of main).
Unnecessary memory allocation
There is no reason to use new on the RingBuffer class, just allocate it on the stack.

The code overwrites object memory in push(). For anything besides trivial types this will be problematic (memory leaks, crashes).
The name RingBuffer can be a bit misleading, maybe rename it to something like BlockingQueue?
Instead of managing a raw T* buffer pointer, it'll likely be better if you used std::queue.
This will not work if there are multiple concurrent consumer or provider threads (for example they may end up setting the same next_idx multiple times and have a race condition on creating T).
The args used when creating T in push() are always passed by const reference, making it impossible to use T's move-constructor ( Like, push(std::move(T())) will still invoke the copy-constructor).

I didn't use std::queue directly mainly because its not thread-safe. Also, cannot pre-allocate memory.

For trivial types, do you mean types that might internally allocate more memory? Could defining an explicit destructor for T helps?

Don’t use std::queue. Like… ever. And especially as an implementation detail. For this, you could use std::vector. It doesn’t matter that it is not thread safe—neither is the raw array you’re using, after all. The whole point of your class is that it is providing the thread safety.

“Trivial type” is a rough category of type that is just a “bag of bits” that you could safely treat as raw memory. What the reviewer is saying is that because you are only testing with a trivial type, even though your code is stomping over objects over and over, you aren’t seeing any negative consequences because… it’s just a bag of bits. If you actually want to view the catastrophe happening, you should use a more complicated type (in this case, a type with a non-trivial destructor will do). I recommend a “barking/meowing type”.

@GabriellaChaos In case you want it pre-allocated you could use an array of std::optional. That will handle everything related to memory alignment and ensure proper handling of object life-time (if synchronized correctly).
